# regex to start and end with different conditions

Tags: regex

The following rules apply to the string I need to test:

- must start with only letters(1 or more)
- can contain letters, numbers and/or underscores ( _ ) (0 or more)
- must end with letters or numbers (1 or more)

`^[a-z]+[\w]*[a-z0-9]$/gi` is the closest I got but it doesn't match a string that contains a single letter.

Examples that should match:

- test_regex_9
- e
- test9

Examples that should not match:

- test_
- _test
- 9test

`^[a-z]+[\w]*[a-z0-9]*$/gi` also allows the string to end with _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way with regex alternation group:

```
^([a-z]+[\w]*[a-z0-9]|[a-z]+)$
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I must say, that @Wiktor Stribiżew pattern will go slightly faster

Answer (score 2):

You may use an optional group:

```
/^[a-z]+(?:\w*[a-z0-9])?$/i
```

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - one or more letters
- `(?:\w*[a-z0-9])?` - one or zero occurrences of

  - `\w*` - 0 or more word chars
  - `[a-z0-9]` - one alphanumeric char
- `$` - end of string.